# Integral function in InfluxDB not returning any data

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

I'm trying to get a graph total power usage for specific periods of time (e.g. by hour).  Currently my power data is stored in an influxdb database every 6 seconds.

I can get a graph of the current usage using the mean function, but using the integral function returns no data points.  Below is the query that I am attempting:

```
SELECT
    integral("value")
FROM
   "Sensor_Power"
WHERE
   $timeFilter
GROUP BY
   time(1h) fill(null)
```

This is using Grafana v4.4.1 and InfluxDB 1.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Influx DB 1.3.1 resolved this.